# Object oriented design - working with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, text-files

I'm working on the same assignment in this link:

[Storing User Input into an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817553/storing-user-input-into-an-array?answertab=active#tab-top)

I've written the array and everything however I want to set this out using objects and methods, however I'm struggling to grasp how to go about doing this?

Is there any way the ships can be added to a 'waiting list' of some kind and added once the available space is found? And lastly how can I 'log' any movements/time of movement into a text file?

Any help would be so so appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO Caitlin!  Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on asking a question. In this specific case you'll want to show what you've already tried and explain why it is not working.

Comment: Show us some code, and ask for something more specific, as is, this is too broad

Comment: When thinking object-oriented, a good place to start is by naming the different "things" that the assignment is about. Each "thing" is typically translated into a class, different types of a "thing" are translated to subclasses, and at last relationships between "things" are expressed through variables. From the first paragraph in the text, the following "things" are mentioned: Port, dock, ship, space. These will all be classes. Furthermore, both ship and space are divided into 'small', 'medium' and 'large' which will be subclasses. I'll leave you to work out the relationships, coz comment ful

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList to help you with this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Ship> shipList = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    shipList.add(aShip); //adds a new ship to the shipList
}
```

What this does is it creates an ArrayList of type Ship (I assume you are using a class called Ship for you ships) into which you can store waiting ships. As soon as a space is available in your dock you can iterate through your ArrayList until you find the first ship which fits in the open space and then fill that open space with the ship:

```
for (Ship waitingShip : shipList) {
    if (waitingShip.size() <= freeSize) {
        // freeSize is the size of the berth that was opened up as an integer
        shipList.remove(waitingShip); // Removes the waitingShip from shipList
        // Add code here to add the waitingShip to your dock
        break; //Makes sure you only add one new ship to your dock by cutting off the for loop
    }
}
```

This assumes that your Ship class has a method size() which can tell you the size of your ship.

Answer (score 0):

To use objects and methods you might want to make 3 different dock objects that need an array of boat objects
so something like this

```
public class dock{
   myBoats[];
   void dock(boat[] boats){
         myBoats= Arrays.copyOf(boats,boats.length);
   }
   public boat getBoats(){return myBoats;}


}
```

the boat class would be something like this

```
public class boat{
int mySize;
    void boat(int inSize){
mySize = inSize;
}
}
```